# issue in reading n number of values from a csv file header in python

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file (tab delimited) whose sample format is:

```
"col1   col2    col3    col4    col5"
"15 AMC 0.0 0.0 0.0"
```

Now I have a variable `n` which denotes the number of values that I want to read from the header of this csv file. So if `n = 3` so I want to read first 3 values in the header and form a list like `['col1','col2','col3']`. I wrote this code to read tab delimited csv file but I am having some issue:

```
n = 3 # number of values to be extracted from header of csv.Will vary

file = open('file1.csv','rU')
read = csv.reader(file,delimiter='\t')

row_number = 0

for row in read:
    if row_number == 0:
       header = row
       break
```

When I do `print header` I get `['col1\tcol2\tcol3\tcol4\tcol5']`. How can I extract the `n` number of values from the header of the csv file?

Comment: This means your file is not tab delimited.

Comment: If those quotes `"` are actually in the file, they will quote the entire line as one text column. Double quotes are the default `quotechar`.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid But you can see the tabs `\t` when the OP prints `header`

Comment: Look at carefully, `col1\col2\tcol3` - they are not tab delimited, otherwise the output would not contain one line.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Hmm.. There's a tab between cols 2 and 3.  See my other comment: they are not split because the whole line is quoted.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid That was a typo from my part. there `\t` printed between each col name when I print header

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that the double quotes (`"`) are in the file as you show them, so they will quote the whole line and delimiters are ignored within quoted strings. You would have to strip those quotes before handing the lines to the csv reader:

```
file = open('file1.csv','rU')

lines = [line.strip().strip('"') for line in file]  # strip white space, too, to be sure

read = csv.reader(lines, delimiter='\t')  
# any iterable producing strings will do in the reader constructor
```

Comment: I didn't noticed that `"` is making the whole line strings. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is not a CSV file, but simply a file with two lines that are quoted. Trying to parse this with the `csv` module will just lead to errors.

Instead, do this:

```
n = 3

with open('file1.csv') as f
   header = next(f)[1:-1].split('')
   print('Header: {}'.format(header))
   print('First {} columns of header: {}'.format(n, header[:n]))
   for line in f:
      row = line[1:-1].split('')
      print('Complete row: {}'.format(row))
      print('First {} columns: {}'.format(n, row[:n]))
```

Answer (score -1):

My guess is that it doesn't split it is because it's not delimited by tab but by 4 spaces. To get only an amount of n you write row[:n].
Try this:

```
n = 3 # number of values to be extracted from header of csv.Will vary

file = open('file1.csv','rU')
read = csv.reader(file,delimiter=' '*4)

row_number = 0

for row in read:
    if row_number == 0:
       header = row[:n]
       break
```

Comment: The question contains convincing evidence that there are in fact tabs between the words, not spaces. And it shows the actual problem as discovered by @schwobaseggl.